# Multicolumn text centering in table with column merging

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I would like to align Euclidean_L1 text is in **center**. I am generating tables from Excel2Latex plugin where everything is fine despite of **"Euclidean_L1"**

**Code**

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccr}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Models} & \multicolumn{5}{p{15.215em}}{Euclidean\_L1} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & Prec  & Recall & F1-Sco & Acc   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AUC} \\
    \midrule
    OpenFace & 52.41 & 53.69 & 53.04 & 52.67 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{55} \\
    DeepID & 52.75 & 38.97 & 44.83 & 52.24 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{52.51} \\
    DeepFace & 53    & 45.08 & 48.72 & 52.76 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{54.03} \\
    FaceNet & 56.75 & 57.94 & 57.34 & 57.08 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{62.25} \\
    \midrule
    VGGFace & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{64.27}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{48.98}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{55.59}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{61.04}} &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: \multicolumn{5}{c}{Euclidean\_L1}  horizontally centers the text.

Comment: Thank you. So what is this text {p{15.215em}}?

Comment: Width of  column or cell in your case: it is equal to 15.215 widths of letter M. Content in this column is justified and can have many lines. In the case of the short one line text, as is your case, it will start at left border of cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to horizontally center the contents of the `\multicolumn`, use `c` instead of `p{15.215em}`.

I have also simplified your code a bit by using the predefined color `red` and I also removed all unnecessary `\multicolumn{1}{c}` commands.

For comparison, I also included a second example, in which I used `siunitx` to improve the alignment of the numbers in the table. (Also, do you really need a red color *and*  bold text to highlight the numbers in the last column? Wouldn't one of the be already sufficient?)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}


%%% only used in the second example code:
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd{\Red}{\color{red}}
\robustify\bfseries

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Models} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Euclidean\_L1} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & Prec  & Recall & F1-Sco & Acc   & {AUC} \\
    \midrule
    OpenFace & 52.41 & 53.69 & 53.04 & 52.67 & 55 \\
    DeepID & 52.75 & 38.97 & 44.83 & 52.24 & 52.51 \\
    DeepFace & 53    & 45.08 & 48.72 & 52.76 & 54.03 \\
    FaceNet & 56.75 & 57.94 & 57.34 & 57.08 & 62.25 \\
    \midrule
    VGGFace & \textcolor{red}{\textbf{64.27}} & \textcolor{red}{\textbf{48.98}} & \textcolor{red}{\textbf{55.59}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{61.04}} &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{5}{S[table-format=2.2, detect-weight]}}
    \toprule
    Models & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Euclidean\_L1} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & {Prec}  & {Recall} & {F1-Sco} & {Acc}   & {AUC} \\
    \midrule
    OpenFace & 52.41 & 53.69 & 53.04 & 52.67 & 55 \\
    DeepID & 52.75 & 38.97 & 44.83 & 52.24 & 52.51 \\
    DeepFace & 53    & 45.08 & 48.72 & 52.76 & 54.03 \\
    FaceNet & 56.75 & 57.94 & 57.34 & 57.08 & 62.25 \\
    \midrule
    VGGFace & \Red 64.27 & \bfseries 48.98 & \Red\bfseries 55.59 & 61.04 &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


\end{document}
```